# MonoDroid OnFocusChangeListener

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have only been working with android app development for a few days so please pardon my ignorance.  I am trying to set up a listener for an EditText that will fire after the field has lost focus.  I have found a few examples in java, but can't find one for monodroid.  How do I set this up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [FocusChange](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=E:Android.Views.View.FocusChange) event:

```
editText.FocusChange += (object sender, View.FocusChangeEventArgs e) =>
                        {
                            // do stuff
                        };
```

Comment: That works beautifully.  However, an unexpected issue is that the focus change event fires when the activity first loads.  Probably because the code is in the OnCreate block.  How would I include this code in my activity outside of the OnCreate.  Again, sorry for my newbie-ness.  :)

Comment: Tough to say without context of what you're doing, but an activity has a series of callbacks during its lifecycle, so you may want to explore that to see what makes sense for what you're doing: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Lifecycle  You can also check e.HasFocus to differentiate between gaining and losing focus.